# How to insert the maximum of five elements in a list having to use Socket?

Tags: java

The cod below is generating the error:

> Thread Type mismastch;cannot convert form String to Set

Why is this and I how can I fix my code?

```
private Set<String> LISTA_DE_NOMES = new HashSet<String>();
private Set<String>nomeCliente;

public boolean armazena(Set<String> newName){
     if (nomeCliente.contains(newName)){
             return false;
     } 
     return nomeCliente.add(newName);
}

Usando conjunto !!!
 public synchronized boolean armazena(Set<String>newName){
        if (LISTA_DE_NOMES.contains(nomeCliente)){
                return false;
        } 
        return LISTA_DE_NOMES.addAll(nomeCliente);
   }
    public synchronized boolean canAddNewUser(Set<String>newName){
        return  (LISTA_DE_NOMES.size()<5);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the code for `HashSet.contains()` is:

```
  public boolean contains(Object o) { 
return map.containsKey(o);
  }
```

you are passing in to your `LISTA_DE_NOMES` (which is a `HashSet<String>`) a `Set`.  The call to `containsKey` is expecting a `String`.